# Shopify API - Set different prices for foreign currencies to specific VariantID

Tags: rest, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I need to send API call to set different prices for each currency to specific VariantID. The shop is set to base on GBP. Somehow I need pass the prices for each currencies for specific VariantID

I can see in shopify settings -> markets -> EU -> there is an pricelist for EUR, I can change price manually, but I need to pass these values via API.

I been trying to using (REST API) PUT method to endpoint **myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/variants/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json**

with body

```
{
    "variant": {
        "id": xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        "presentment_prices": [
            {
                "price": {
                    "amount": "100.00",
                    "currency_code": "EUR"
                },
                "compare_at_price": null
            },
            {
                "price": {
                    "amount": "7.00",
                    "currency_code": "GBP"
                },
                "compare_at_price": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As the result

```
{
"variant": {
    "id": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    "product_id": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    "price": "12.00"
    "presentment_prices": [
        {
            "price": {
                "amount": "14.95",
                "currency_code": "EUR"
            },
            "compare_at_price": null
        },
        {
            "price": {
                "amount": "12.00",
                "currency_code": "GBP"
            },
            "compare_at_price": null
        }
    ],
    "requires_shipping": true
}
```

}

I getting 200 OK - which is confusing me, the values are not updated, and not matching

As you can see the price should be set to £7 and €100

but in reality the price is £12 and €15 as is set in market
[image]
[image]

As you can see on screenshots it's getting confusing me, Would do you please advise how can I provide correct prices for each currencies to Shopify via API Call?

It can be REST API or GraphQL, anything - Please advise if you have any knowlage/experience on this scenario

Thanks